# 2002 Camry making dragging noise

Tags: noise

I have a 2002 Camry. I have been noticing a dragging sound from the left front side. The noise is when acceleration at start up and lower speeds. When cruise is engaged, there is no sound. About January, we had snow in Louisiana, and being from the south had no idea how to drive on icy roads and therefore slid into a ditch, just the front end. I don'tthink know if this is causing the noise from some damage. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

check to see if the wheel well baffle is loose.  My wife is having hers fixed tomorrow.  If you're getting a loudish noise it could be hitting the wheel.